# Low Power library messing up serial text

Tags: serial, power, baud-rate

I noticed something unusual using the Low Power library today.
When printing text in the loop and using `LowPower.powerDown(SLEEP_1S, ADC_OFF, BOD_OFF);` to sleep for one second, all the text in the loop gets messed up in the Serial Monitor as if you chose the wrong baud rate.

Example code:

```c
#include "LowPower.h"

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println(F("HELLO"));
  Serial.println(F("HELLO")); 
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println(F("HELLO"));
  LowPower.powerDown(SLEEP_1S, ADC_OFF, BOD_OFF);
}
```

This code just prints

```
����11=C!�11=C!�11=C!�11=C!�11=C!�11=C!�11=C!�11=C!�11=C!�11=C!�11=C!�11=C!�11=C!�11=C!�11=C!�11=C!�11=C!�11=C!�11=C!�11=C!�11=C!�11=C!�11=C!�11=
```

even when using different baud rates. (I used the same baud rate on both the arduino and the monitor).
Replacing the low power command with `delay(1000);` works fine

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is most likely that the system is going to sleep *while* it's still sending the serial data.

Forcing all the serial data to be sent before you go to sleep should fix the problem (serial data is sent in the background using an interrupt so as to keep sketch slowdown to a minimum):

```
Serial.flush();
LowPower.powerDown(SLEEP_1S, ADC_OFF, BOD_OFF);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this fast answer. Would this affect the power saving of the library? I assume not but better be sure :)

Comment: It will cause a slight delay before it goes to sleep while the serial data is sent out.  It won't affect the actual sleeping though, no.  It just means the "on" time will be slightly longer - long enough to finish what it's doing.

Comment: I didn't know of that method. Thanks. @qwertz using a higher baudrate than 9600 will decrease the transmit time, so reduce power usage.

Comment: @Gerben In pre-1.0.0 Serial.flush wiped the transmit buffer.  In 1.0.0 and onwards it blocks until the transmit buffer is empty and the UART hardware has transmitted the last bit.

Comment: Let us know if this doesn't totally solve it. There may be other issues as well like the serial line stopping being driven high.